# Porting Java applications running on Websphere 7 from Solaris to RHEL

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-7

I have some requirement to port the java applications running on WAS 7.0.0.31 cluster from Solaris to RHEL OS. It's WAS ND package and in both servers we will be using same versions of jdk & WAS. Please could you suggest the exact process if anyone has done it before. I'm thinking of export and import WAS configuration but not very sure though whether it would work as expected or not. If that doesn't work, could you advise how to proceed?

Comment: Are you looking to move only the applications, or the applications & the server configuration?

Comment: I am planning to move applications and server configurations as well...infact, am trying to move entire Websphere configuration including apps over to new server with RHEL OS